# How to add an image to replace the font pictogram in a button

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xynmmqk/1/

HTML:

```
<button class="facebook">Reopen Task</button>
```

I would like to replace the white "rectangle" to be replaced with an unlock icon (what font has the unlock icon?). I would preferebly would like an image but didn't know how to add an image there.

I would like the end result to be:

[image]

I tried something but didn't quite work: http://jsfiddle.net/5xynmmqk/2/

Comment: Well, can't you use top, left values to put the icon into the right place? - http://jsfiddle.net/5xynmmqk/3/

Comment: @sdcr: also change _top_ in _button:active:before_

Comment: [font awesome unlock icon](http://fontawesome.info/website-lists-and-examples-using-font-awesome-icon-css/icon-unlock-alt)

Comment: @A.Akram sure, i was just asking, it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @sdcr Thanks. That did the work, how can I make a shadow on "active" like in the character font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [locked lock](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f512/index.htm):  which you can get with `&#128274;` and `&#x1f512;`. Or, you can (probably should) use [Font Awesome lock](http://fontawesome.io/icon/lock/) which looks the same on all platforms.

Here's an [unlocked lock](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f513/index.htm):  which again you can get with `&#128274;` or `&#x1f513;`. And the [Font Awesome equivalent](http://fontawesome.io/icon/unlock-alt/).

Anyway, if you want to use an image instead (which would ensure that it always looks the same regardless of the platform and character support), you can use `background-image:url(image-path-here.svg)`. Then you'll just have to use `background-position` to position it correctly.

Comment: Thanks. In mobile it was really colorful but in my PC it is black and white. I will definitely go with an image :)

Comment: I edited in Font Awesome equivalents, those look the same on all platforms. They're easier to use than images.

Comment: Thank you. But they are still black and white in my PC. Oh I guess i can change the font color...

Comment: I thought that's what you were after. Flat icons are in. You can always change the font color to recolor them. If you end up using an image anyway, *please* use SVG so it won't look absolutely awful on mobile.

Comment: Of course, flat wouldn't be so bad. Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xynmmqk/5/. Please help me replace the image with the icon.